# how to insert DateTime.Now values into datetime type field in sql database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, webforms

my code is :

```
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=haftehbazardb;Integrated Security=True ");
    SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();


    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("Insert into Table_test(date1,date2) Values({0},{1})", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(21));
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cn.Close();

    Label1.Text = "Insert is done successfuly!";
```

I can insert evry type values into database.but i can not insert `datetime.now` or `datetime.now.addday(21)`  into this database.type values `date1` AND `date2` is datetime.

Comment: what is the error? what is the type of the fields on the DB?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using parameterized queries.

```
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Table_test(date1,date2) Values(@Now,@21DaysLater)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Now", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@21DaysLater", DateTime.Now.AddDays(21));
```

It would be a good idea to insert all of your values, not just DateTime using parameters. Don't use string concatenation to write SQL.

Comment: Also take into account that the `Add(string, Object)` method overload is obsolete since .NET 2.0, because of possible ambiguity with another `Add` overload which takes `SqlDbType` as a second parameter. So it is safer to always use `AddWithValue(string, Object)` method instead of `Add(string, Object)`.

Comment: Thanks Alexander I forgot about this.